# Can't find input element within div, selenium java eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

[Attached is the HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3OCt.png)

I am trying to find the input element with value "Save and Return."

I have tried to find it with xpath to the value text like so:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@value,'Save and Return']")).click();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value=\\"Save and Return\\"]"));
```

Tell me if it doesn't work. Give more details about the errors. I might have mistaken about the escape characters \\ in the string.

Comment: The escape characters weren't right but I tried:
`driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value='Save and Return']")).click();`
and that worked! Thanks man!